# Fazer busca em várias tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: mysql, sql

Colegas.

Preciso fazer uma busca em várias tabelas ( um total de 28 ) onde cada tabela corresponde a um estado do Brasil. Essa busca seria do CEP, que é um dos campos dessas tabelas. Inner Join não sei se seria a solução, senão eu teria que dar inner em todas as tabelas. Teria alguma outra solução?

Comment: Qual o campo vai ser usado para critério na busca?

Comment: Olá Fernando. O campo será o cep.

Comment: Não tenho certeza agora, mas se não me engano cada estado tem um range de CEP. Se tu souber esse range, já dá pra saber direto em que tabela procurar.

Comment: Perdão Fernando, não consegui compreender. O que seria range exatamente? Os campos que compõe todas as tabelas são: id, cidade, logradouro, bairro, cep e tp_logradouro. São os mesmos campos para todas as tabelas

Comment: Você pode utilizar views para otimizar a busca, veja algumas vantagens:

Visualize os dados sem armazenar os dados no objeto.
Limitar a exibição de uma tabela ex. pode ocultar algumas das colunas nas tabelas.
Junte duas ou mais tabelas e mostre como um único objeto para o usuário.
Restringir o acesso de uma tabela para que ninguém pode inserir novas linhas.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302615/mysql-views-performance

Comment: Por que esses dados não estão em uma unica tabela?

Comment: Porque estou criando um sistema onde o usuário irá digitar um CEP e aparecerá automaticamente o logradouro, estado e cidade. Baseado no republicavirtual.com.br/, baixei o SQL deles, porém não quero ficar refém de servidores externos para trazer esse resultado. O SQL deles já vem dessa forma. Uma base chamada CEP e várias tabelas com o nome dos estados (sp, rj, mg,...).

Comment: Achei muito abstrato essa pergunta, elabore melhor a estrutura das tabelas, qual a informação você quer e qual filtro precisa usar.

Comment: Entendi. De qualquer forma você poderia juntar todas essas tabelas que você baixou em apenas uma para facilitar a sua pesquisa, ou você vai ter de pesquisar na tabela correta em função do cep informado. Ou junta tudo através de um UNION ALL e pesquise na tabela resultante, mas performance vai ficar ruim.

Answer (score 1):

Na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C%C3%B3digo_de_Endere%C3%A7amento_Postal&oldid=47623335) tem informações de como funciona a estrutura de um CEP:

### Estados

- 0xxxx:

  - Grande São Paulo (01000-09999)
- 1xxxx:

  - Interior e litoral de São Paulo (11000-19999)
- 2xxxx:

  - Rio de Janeiro (20000-28999)
  - Espírito Santo (29000-29999)
- 3xxxx:

  - Minas Gerais (30000-39990)
- 4xxxx:

  - Bahia (40000-48999)
  - Sergipe (49000-49999)
- 5xxxx:

  - Pernambuco (50000-56999)
  - Alagoas (57000-57999)
  - Paraíba (58000-58999)
  - Rio Grande do Norte (59000-59999)
- 6xxxx:

  - Ceará (60000-63990)
  - Piauí (64000-64990)
  - Maranhão (65000-65990)
  - Pará (66000-68890)
  - Amapá (68900-68999)
  - Amazonas (69000-69299, 69500-69999)
  - Acre (69400-69499)
  - Roraima (69300-69399)
    7xxxx: - Distrito Federal (70000-73699)
  - Goiás (73700-76799)
  - Rondônia (76800-76999)
  - Tocantins (77000-77999)
  - Mato Grosso (78000-78899)
  - Mato Grosso do Sul (79000-79999)
- 8xxxx:

  - Paraná (80000-87999)
  - Santa Catarina (88000-89999)
    9xxxx:
  - Rio Grande do Sul (90000-99999)

### Componentes

```
X____-___: Região
_X___-___: Sub-região
__X__-___: Setor
___X_-___: Subsetor
____X-___: Divisor de subsetor
_____-XXX: Sufixo de distribuição
```

Com esses dados fica evidente que é só pegar o primeiro dígito do CEP e tu já tem a informações de qual tabela no BD ele pode estar.

Comment: Estou me baseando nesse site, porém quero que a busca ocorra dentro do meu servidor, para não depender do servidor externo. Vejam: http://www.republicavirtual.com.br/busca_de_cep/PHP/#php Em Exemplos, tem como baixar o SQL dos CEP/Cidades

Answer (score 1):

Criei uma nova resposta por ter uma abordagem completamente diferente da anterior.

Verifiquei o banco de dados que está utilizando e com duas queries dá para retornar o logradouro do CEP.

1. Uma query para descobrir de que estado é o CEP
2. Outra query para descobrir de que cidade e logradouro.

**Passo 1**

```sql
-- Exemplo: CEP 97060-003
SELECT 
    uf.UF,
    uf.Nome
FROM uf
WHERE "97060" BETWEEN uf.Cep1 AND uf.Cep2;

+----+-------------------+
| uf |       Nome        |
+----+-------------------+
| RS | Rio Grande do Sul |
+----+-------------------+
```

**Passo 2**

Guarde o campo UF em uma variável e faça a próxima pesquisa

```sql
-- Exemplo: CEP 97060-003
SELECT *
FROM rs as uf
WHERE uf.cep = "97060-003"

+-------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------+
|  id   |   cidade    |        logradouro        | bairro |    cep    | tp_logradouro |
+-------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------+
| 20410 | Santa Maria | Nossa Senhora Medianeira | Centro | 97060-003 | Avenida       |
+-------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

Não sei em que linguagem está programando, mas é bem simples.
A primeira pesquisa é feita com os 5 primeiros dígitos (`99999`).
Enquanto a segunda é feita com todos os dígitos e com o hífen(`99999-999`).